# Dual reading (for translation comparison)

Tags: epub, software, apps

I have started using my tablet for reading epubs and I have found a lot of different versions of the same book.

So, is there any application that allows me to compare, i.e. to see both versions in a split screen?

I thought it would be easy to find this because it is such a useful utility!

I have tried the 10 most used application for reading epubs and no single one allows me to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a special PC/Android app that for that: [Aglona Reader](https://sites.google.com/site/aglonareader/home/lang-en).
It uses its own XML format, though.
I.e. you'd have write your own converter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what device you are using, but on a Galaxy Note 10.1 or higher you can use the split window function to run two different epub readers and compare them side to side if that is your objective.

Answer (score 0):

What I haven't used myself, but what you probably could use is Calibre's [book comparison feature](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/diff.html).

What I have done myself for comparisons of EPUBs on the level of the the HTML files using [`tidy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Tidy) to standardise the indentation (if necessary) and then using [`xxdiff`](http://furius.ca/xxdiff/) to visually compare the files.

This is not the same as split screen view of the **rendered** file. I agree that would sometimes be useful, but the same (pixel) arrangements can be achieved in an unlimited number of ways. A comparison on the basis of the actual text content (to find out e.g. which scan typos were fixed in which version) would have to do so based on versions of the ebook data without the formatting as well.

Answer (score 0):

@anthon is right
I also use calibre for book comparison feature

Next, when I need to visually compare html pages I use an html with two iFrame, I open the same file into both and then, with some little javascript code, I move up and down the text in a semi sync mode (readjusting manually the pages)

It works fine for my job, maybe not for normal readings.
^__^